# Public Access with Symfony's AbstractAuthenticator

Tags: symfony

I'm exploring the new system for User Authentication using the new AbstractAuthenticator class in my symfony 5 project.

My symfony app will contain a mix of routes, some will only be accessible to authenticated users and some for unauthenticated users (public access)

My security.yaml file looks something like this:

```
security:

    enable_authenticator_manager: true

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
          custom_authenticators:
            - App\Security\JwtAuthenticator

    access_control:
      - { path: ^/auth/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
      - { path: ^/auth, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

I have also setup a route to auth/login

However, when I access the url https://myapp.test/auth/login I get the following message:

```
{"message":"Invalid credentials."}
```

If I remove the custom authenticator directive from security.yaml the url loads as expected.

Below is the authenticate function from the Authenticator class:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request): PassportInterface
{
    return new SelfValidatingPassport(new UserBadge($request->get('email));
}
```

if I access /auth/login with a valid user matching the email address provided and with the ROLE_USER role, the page will load as expected.  If I access it without providing an email address, the page will return the following (from the onAuthenticationFailure method):

```
{"message":"Invalid credentials."}
```

If I understand correctly, as stated in Symfony docs, the PUBLIC_ACCESS should skip authenticating the user and load the /auth/login route, while everything else under /auth/ should be protected.  But I cannot get the PUBLIC_ACCESS directive to work.

Comment: When you say the page is not displayed do you mean you get a blank page?  If so then that implies that you are not running in the usual development/debug mode.  I assume you are not posting your complete security.yaml file?  Typically you would only need the PUBLIC_ACCESS if you are trying to access something that is already protected.  Like if you had ^/auth ROLE_ADMIN.  In any event I suspect the real problem is your authenticator.  Does it work without any access_control?

Comment: If I remove the access control directive, I still get the blank page.  So the auth/login controller code is never executed.   If I remove the firewall altogether in security.yaml the page will load just fine.  My understanding was that declaring the route as public_access would bypass the firewall altogether.  Is this not the case?  do I need to add anything in my AbstractAuthenticator class which would let this route load without any security checks?

Comment: I do think you are misunderstanding PUBLIC_ACCESS.  There is a section in the docs on it.  The example says that anything under /admin needs a ROLE_ADMIN except for /admin/login.  Bottom line is that you should not need any access_control to get your app working.  The first thing to solve is why you are getting a blank page.  You should be running in development mode and you should be using the Symfony development server.  You should never get a blank page but rather some big 'exception' type page.  I suppose you could try checking the logs.

Comment: Did you use make:auth to get started?  I ask because your posted main firewall configuration does not match the default configuration.

Comment: I've updated my original post with a few more details, and fixed the blank page issue.  However the initial issue remains that symfony is still guarding /auth/login when it shouldn't.  Basically I would like it so that anything under auth irequires user authentication (I've got this part working) with exception of /auth/login which should not require any authentication

Comment: Have you managed to figure this out? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it by changing the location of `custom_authenticators` like that:

```
security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true

    firewalls:
     main:
            json_login:                   # that is my login for rest api
                provider: user_provider
                check_path: api_login
     api:
            pattern: ^/api
            custom_authenticators:        # here is the location for my custom authenticator
                - App\Security\Authenticator
            stateless: true

     access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
```

I hope it helps!